# Convert multiple input levels into number

Tags: sensor

**Current Setup**
I have created a working circuit for water level detection, using LEDs. I have inserted a plastic rod into the water tank, and soldered wires at 7 levels. As the water rises, the circuit completes via each wire and the LED for that wire lights up on my circuit board / bread board. Something like this - [link](http://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/water-level-indicator-alarm-circuit).

As the water level rises, each wire/line becomes a high i.e. has voltage/current on it and hence the LED on that line lights up. Hence, at level 3, the wires are (top level to low level) 0000111; at level 5 it is 0011111 and full level it is 1111111 and zero level is 0000000.

**My requirement**
I want to connect this to a set of 3.3V digital GPIOs.

**Question**
How do i connect this? Even if i can, is there a cleaner way to make just 1 or 2 connections by placing some sort of decoder/encoder in between?

Comment: Parallel in, serial out [shift register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_register).  But I think an issue with connecting this directly to that or the pi is the amount of voltage it takes to count as "high" in digital logic is going to be a lot more precise than what it takes to light an LED.

Comment: Do you want to leave the LEDs in place or can you change? You circuit is current driven rather than voltage so maybe best solution is to have opto-couplers in parallel with the LEDs and take your digital output from this.

Answer (score 0):

If you used just one conductor (stripped of insulation) dangling in the water you would get an analogue current rising as the water level rose\$^1\$. This could develop a voltage across a resistor that could be digitized by an ADC (analogue to digital converter). The ADC would need probably only three IO connections namely start_convert, clock and data out i.e. two outputs and one input. You could use a 16 bit ADC and get a lot more resolution than what you currently have but, they are just numbers so having too much resolution isn't really a problem.

If you are insisting on using your original probe then use a serial to parallel encoder as mentioned in the comments but make sure that the voltage in levels are capped to a suitable voltage using a zener diode.

---

\$^1\$ - Disclaimer - I know nothing about how the water might ultimately eat away at this probe due to the current flowing and I wouldn't recommend either probe for use in drinking water or where the water is expected to be uncontaminated. This also applies to fish ponds - I wouldn't want to be blamed for electrocuting a prize koi carp.